# Repeating failed XHR request in couchbase deployed in ec2 machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, couchbase

This error occurs when I view a document or a view in the couchbase admin console hosted on an ec2 machine. Apparently this is a bug they're not planning to fix(http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/MB-4144). what should I do?